# Concise synonym for "black-box" (adjective)

Tags: synonyms, political-correctness

In my field, a "black box" is a device or piece of software whose inner workings are not exposed or documented: something that you can treat as a sealed, opaque object whose behaviour is known or at least observable but how that behaviour is implemented is hidden.  "Black-box" can be used as an adjective; "black-box testing" is testing the behaviour of a device or piece of software without any information about its inner workings (design schematics, source code, etc.), while "white-box testing" is doing the same *with* access to information about its inner workings.

Within the last few years, there has been a trend towards viewing many uses of "black" as disparaging to people whose ancestry disposes them to heavily melanised skin.  I am being asked to replace my uses of "black-box" with something else.  We've replaced "white-box" with things like "code-assisted" and "design-assisted" (where "code" refers to software source code).  However, I'm having trouble coming up with a *concise* synonym for "black-box" that people understand.  I tried "zero-knowledge" but that seemed to confuse everyone.  "Code-deprived" seems too negative.  What are some alternatives?

Comment: Apparently, “black box” is still a common,  unprejudiced expression in computer science. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box

Comment: Unfortunately, the decision to avoid terms employing "black" or "white" has been made by management and I am not in a position to appeal that decision.

Comment: The best I can think of is "opaque". This is already used for data structures in software.

Comment: How about a **grey box**?  :) As in [grey area](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grey-area). Even if you think you know something about it, it would be uncertain.

Comment: Instead of worrying about physical terms for metaphors, why not just use the term that it metaphorizes? All these boxes are in fact functions -- they have inputs and they have outputs and they are consistently linked in ways we don't know in detail, just like you don't know or care what algorithm is being used to calculate a value. It's the input and the output that counts; that's why the box can be black instead of transparent.

Comment: How about _uninformed_ testing? Other ideas that came to mind include _shadow-box, code-opaque, code-oblivious_ etc.

Comment: before there were (plastic) black boxes, there were magic boxes. https://towardsdatascience.com/magic-boxes-machine-learning-why-we-need-to-stop-using-the-black-box-metaphor-c9f345d1bc12

Comment: The hidden workings of the black box equate to a **lockbox**. No entry, no access, taken as is. However, it's perfectly acceptable corporate behavior to ask for a replacement for a newly objectionable term. Otherwise, management has you playing Fetch Me a Rock, the game of undefined requirements: "No, not that rock.  A different rock." "Waddya mean black can't be a slurred reference to a skin tone that no humans have? I have this PC problem, and you must solve it yourself."

Comment: There's a distinction between being locked out - prevented from knowing - and fundamentally not being able to know what went on, as is the case with advanced self learning AIs.

Comment: The word "encapsulation" is used in object-oriented programming; maybe "capsule" would fit as a replacement for black-box, though it's not an established usage.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - You can avoid all your PC problems by switching to a mac.  ;-)

Comment: Interesting question. You don't want to say *blind testing* — that just moves the issue from race to disability. Perhaps *boxed testing*? Can you add an example sentence with your new white-box terminology and a blank for what you're seeking in place of black-box?

Answer (score 3):

*Opaque/obscured/obfuscated/hidden/unknown*.

The trend you've described, moving from language like white/blacklist to allow/deny list is typically seen as more broad than just aimed at removing potentially racial-charged language. It's often discussed as a move towards more inclusive language (see [this](https://www.aswf.io/blog/inclusive-language/) or [this](https://www.it.northwestern.edu/about/it-projects/dei/glossary.html) or [this](https://developers.google.com/style/inclusive-documentation)).

Part of being inclusive, in this context, means avoiding potentially offensive language.  But another, probably less politically sensitive aspect, is the attempt to make the language easier to understand for people who aren't already *culturally* fluent.

I speak American English natively, have lived nearly my entire life in the US, attended public school and very mainstream universities, am fairly well-read, and when I first heard "black box" in a software development context, I had no idea what it meant.  Was it like an airplane's black box?  Is it supposed to survive a computer crash?  If a blacklist has to do with thing we don't want, and a whitelist has things we do like, is a black-box system worse than a white-box one? (This isn't me being cute - this is actually what I remember thinking at the time).

These kind of obtuse metaphors increase the learning curve for people being on-boarded or educated, and make it difficult to communicate with people who haven't already gone through that process.

Just say what you mean.  If a service or a component is being used without knowledge of its internals, call it an "opaque service/component".  Remember another key software development insight: Don't be clever.

Comment: I would call it "A Mystery Cabinet" - X goes in; something unknown/mysterious happens, and Y comes out.

Answer (score 2):

[Software Testing Help](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/black-box-testing/) gives these alternatives (and [white box](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/white-box-testing-techniques-with-example/?_gl=1*18xc6j9*_ga*YW1wLWY3aGUzaUhhamkyWjZpQVNhLUV1WGFrdVcyVmFqdmdCOGNFcW1CSmpleWlYb0RIQ3NKM2FwYllGczVvTXMyQks.) counterparts, which I've parenthesized):

- behavioral (structural)
- opaque-box (clear-box, glass-box)
- closed-box (open-box)
- specification-based
- eye-to-eye

"Black box" and "white box" are the only names I'm familiar with, however.

Answer (score 0):

With no knowledge of the inner workings of a device the only thing one can do is stimulate it externally and then observe the resulting behavior.  So one might call this ***stimulus-based testing***. Or external stimulus-based (ESB) testing.

Answer (score -1):

**Fusillade box** You are simultaneously fusillading it, aren't you? fusillade([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fusillade)) The simultaneous firing of a number of firearms.
(by extension) A rapid burst. Alternatively you can use "**barrage-box**".

**Canned shut box** can([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canned)) To seal in a can.

**Blind box** You are going in blind.

**Knotty box**, Knot([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knot)) A looping of a piece of string or of any other long, flexible material that cannot be untangled without passing one or both ends of the material through its loops. A tangled clump. A maze-like pattern. A difficult situation.

**Bolted box**, Bolt([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bolt)) A bar of wood or metal dropped in horizontal hooks on a door and adjoining wall or between the two sides of a double door, to prevent the door(s) from being forced open. A small personal-armour-piercing missile for short-range use, or (in common usage though deprecated by experts) a short arrow, intended to be shot from a crossbow or a catapult. An iron to fasten the legs of a prisoner; a shackle; a fetter.